# How to tile textures in Blender 2.8?

Tags: texturing

I'm using Blender 2.8, and the way to make materials that with tiling seems to have been changed? When I resize the UV map, everything outside the image gets black. Is this a bug or a new, smart feature...?[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ah, solved it myself. :)

(Note: Why is this set to "Clip" and not "Repeat" by default in 2.8?)

[image]

Comment: Setting the number of repeats has no effect though.  Rendering the repeat feature useless.